# C# Gray out a control and draw another on it

Tags: c#, controls, drawing, overlay, progress

I´m using WinForms. I want to make a little class, which modifys controls to show it´s working.

I want to draw an overlay over for example a button. It should be a half-transparent gray.
After that i want to draw a ProgressBar on over it (in the center).  Similar to [This](http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/attachment.php?attachmentid=5552), except using a progress bar.

How can i realize this? I don´t want to set the position of the progressbar, just drawing it on the other one.

How could i do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate.....I don't understand your problem.........

Comment: You want a control to be drawn in a specific location but you don't want to position it?

Comment: I think he means to do something similar to the way you can use the image buttons in windows7 taskbar to behave like a progress bar... but on any control in an application.

Comment: What technology are you using?  WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: I´m using WinForms.
I tell it again: I want to draw a overlay above a control with a gray, half-transparent rectangle. On this rectangle, in the center, i want to draw a Progressbar ;)
like this here, but with a progresbar: http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/attachment.php?attachmentid=5552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar before.

You need to use [`Button.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Rectangle)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) to get the image of the button. Then make the Bitmap grayscale ([there are multiple algorithms available for this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale); I have used the last one successfully although probably not originally from this site).

Now, I did this with an entire form instead of a button, but I disabled the form, and then covered the entire form with an image of itself, altered and then covered it with the progress bar (itself in a panel with other controls).

You could just as easily disable the button, cover it with a panel containing the image and the progress bar on top of it.

Comment: If you wanna draw the image as disabled, just use this class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawimagedisabled.aspx